# Inconsistent ROC-AUC

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc, graph-neural-network

I'm training [VGAE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07308.pdf) to predict edges and I'm getting a good loss (BCEwithLogits) values but the ROC-AUC seems bit inconsistent and not very progressive. I'm not sure how to diagnose it.

The model is based on [this](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/link_pred.py) code. I use a custom dataset with many graphs, each with around 10-15 nodes and 15-20 directed edges. Every node has these features:

1. position = bounding box coordinates (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
2. one-hot encoded class label

loss:

[image: loss]

test roc-auc

[image: test roc-auc]

val roc-auc

[image: val roc-auc]

I've played around the hyperparameters and data features however I can't get a nice smooth and consistent line in ROC-AUC. What could be the underlying issues for this?